# Validating XML instance with additional element

Tags: xml, .net-3.5, xsd

I am using XML Schema file to validate an XML instance passed to a web service. I was wondering if it is possible to have some other tags in the XML instance that can be ignored, or is it that if the string does not match "exactly" to the schema it will fail?

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
    <xs:element name="DSSData">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="LTSN" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="Timestamp" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="Stats" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Trp" type="xs:integer" nillable="true" minOccurs="1" />
                            <xs:element name="Keyed" type="xs:integer" nillable="true" minOccurs="1" />
                            <xs:element name="Pieces" type="xs:integer" nillable="true" minOccurs="1" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and I pass the following XML string:

```
<DSSData><LTSN>abcd</LTSN><Timestamp></Timestamp><Stats><Trp>12</Trp><Keyed>34</Keyed><Pieces>12</Pieces><Ocr>45</Ocr><OcrNoBC>87</OcrNoBC></Stats></DSSData>
```

with a new tag `<newTag>` added.

UPDATED:

This is what is used to validate XML:

```
bool bIsValid = ValidXMLDoc(my_xml_string, "", "some_schema.xsd");

public bool ValidXmlDoc(string xml, string sSchemaNamespace, string schemaUri)
{
    try
    {
        // Is the xml string valid?
        if(xml == null || xml.Length <  1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        StringReader srXml = new StringReader(xml);
        return ValidXmlDoc(srXml, sSchemaNamespace, schemaUri);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        this.ValidationError = ex.Message;
        return false;
    }
}

public bool ValidXmlDoc(StringReader xml, string schemaNamespace, string schemaUri)
{
    // Continue?
    if(xml == null || schemaNamespace == null || schemaUri == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    isValidXml = true;
    XmlValidatingReader vr;
    XmlTextReader tr;
    XmlSchemaCollection schemaCol = new XmlSchemaCollection();
    schemaCol.Add(schemaNamespace, schemaUri);
    try 
    { 
        // Read the xml.
        tr = new XmlTextReader(xml);

        // Create the validator.
        vr = new XmlValidatingReader(tr);

        // Set the validation tyep.
        vr.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

        // Add the schema.
        if(schemaCol != null)
        {
            vr.Schemas.Add(schemaCol);
        }
        // Set the validation event handler.
        vr.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);

        // Read the xml schema.
        while(vr.Read()) 
        { 
        } 
        vr.Close(); 
        return isValidXml;
    } 
    catch(Exception ex) 
    { 
        this.ValidationError = ex.Message;
        return false; 
    } 
    finally
    {
        // Clean up...
        vr = null;
        tr = null;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It will not validate.

You can use `<xs:any>` with `processContents="skip"` or `"lax"` as a placeholder for any unvalidated tag in a validated sequence.

For example, if you want to allow an optional arbitrary unvalidated tag at the end of your sequence, you can use:

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Trp" type="xs:integer" nillable="true" minOccurs="1" />
    <xs:element name="Keyed" type="xs:integer" nillable="true" minOccurs="1" />
    <xs:element name="Pieces" type="xs:integer" nillable="true" minOccurs="1" />
    <xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

which will validate your instance:

```
<DSSData>
    <LTSN>abcd</LTSN>
    <Timestamp/>
    <Stats>
        <Trp>12</Trp>
        <Keyed>34</Keyed>
        <Pieces>12</Pieces>
        <newTag>45</newTag>
    </Stats>
</DSSData>
```

If you want to allow *many* unvalidated elements after the three validated ones, you should use `maxOccurs="unbounded"` in `<xs:any>`:

```
<xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

You can test the validation in this [fiddle](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=c5a96071-afbd-4407-9966-6afce9280363-xsdvalidation#.U3owclhdVtM).

Comment: I modified schema as suggested and passed the following XML string and it failed validation:<DSSData><LTSN>DSSDHSDEV</LTSN><Timestamp>5/19/2014 12:07:28 PM</Timestamp> <Stats><Trp>1</Trp><Keyed>0</Keyed><Pieces>1</Pieces><Ocr>0</Ocr><OcrNoBC>0</OcrNoBC></Stats></DSSData>. It seems it took the first "undeclared" element, Ocr, but failed on OcrNoBC element. How do I do this if I don't know how many "undeclared" elements will be there?

Comment: You can test for XSD validation here: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.U3ovJFhdVtM

Comment: I see. You have **2** extra elements. The schema is only allowing one. If you want to allow unbounded extra non-validating elements, then you should add `maxOccurs="unbounded"` to the `<xs:any>`.

Comment: Your last example validated is [here](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=c5a96071-afbd-4407-9966-6afce9280363-xsdvalidation#.U3owclhdVtM)

Comment: It seems when I run the XML string against schema in the link provided it validates. However, it fails in my code. I updated the original post with the functions I am using to validate XML string and can't see why it fails. It retuns: "Could not find schema information for the element 'OcrNoBC'."

Comment: When I trace the code, the error message "Could not find schema information for element 'OcrNoBC'" was the second error; the first one was the same for 'Ocr' element. It seems it doesn;t understand the last element added to schema: <xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>

Comment: I am not sure, since I am not a much of a C# programmer, but shouldn't this line be `schemaCol.Add(null, schemaUri)`? Your schema does not have a namespace, and without that change I was unable to run the parser. I ran your example in Xamarin (Mac OS) and it validated. So unfortunately I cannot reproduce your error.